# Нужно задачать изначальные значения класса конструктором

Tags: python

Нужно задачать изначальные значения класса конструктором

```
import random as rd #завантаження бібліотеки рандом

class Clothes: #створення класу

    def __init__(self,material,price,color,country,sale,size, arr):#створення змінних
        self.material = material
        self.price = price
        self.color = color
        self.country = country
        self.sale = sale
        self.size = size

    def countryPrice(self):#створення метода  залежності ціни від країни
        if self.country == "USA":
            self.price += self.price * 0.1

    def saleofSize(self):#створення метода залежності ціни від розміру
        if self.size_lst == "S":
            self.price -= self.price * 0.6

    def __str__(self):#метод повернення змінних
        return f'material-{self.material}, price- {self.price}, color- {self.color}, country- {self.country}, sale- {self.sale}, size- {self.size}'

lstClass = []#порожній масив
material_lst = ["Кожа","Шелк","Хлопок","Лен"]#створення масива матеріалу
price_lst = [3000,1200,20000,4500, 5500]#створення масива ціни
color_lst = ["Red","Green","Blue","Dark"]#створення масива кольору
country_lst = ["Russia","Ukraine","USA","Portugal"]#створення країни 
sale_lst = [30,1,5,70, 80]#створення масива знижок
size_lst = ["L", "XXL","XL", "S", "M"]#створення масива розміру

print(sorted(price_lst))#метод сортування
print("MIN-",min(price_lst))#метод мінімального елемента ціни
print("MAX-",max(price_lst))#метод максимального елемента ціни
print(sorted(sale_lst))#метод сортування знижки

data_list = (material_lst, price_lst, color_lst, country_lst, sale_lst, size_lst)

for i in range(1,20):
    arg = (rd.choice(obj) for obj in data_list)
    arr = rd.randint(0,100)
    specimen = Clothes(*arg, arr)
    specimen.countryPrice()
    lstClass.append(specimen)

for obj in lstClass:
    print(obj)
```

Comment: так в чем вопрос-то?  можно сказать, что ваш `arr` в классе никак не обрабатывается и ни на что не влияет.
По структуре класа действия  из `countryPrice` и `saleofSize(self)`  логичнее перенести бы, в `__init__`,  но я не знаю условия вашей задачи )))

Comment: нужно переделать на конструктор

Comment: ну так вы и передаете все на конструктор в строке:  `specimen = Clothes(*arg, arr)`

Comment: можно пожалуйста кодом, мой пример у меня не верный

Comment: не вопрос, но вы подробнее опишите суть проблемы. Не ясно что именно нужно. например  надо  `countryPrice` и `saleofSize`  переделать в инит, или что ?? Далее, у вас `arr` в классе никак не обрабатывается. Он зачем-то нужен? Что он должен делать? Опишите, что именно неправильно. Дополните ваш вопрос. подправьте его. и постараюсь помочь кодом ).
.
можно тупо удалить строчи с `def countryPrice` и `def saleofSize`  и все заработает )))

Comment: да, надо countryPrice и saleofSize переделать в инит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Clothes: #створення класу

    def __init__(self,material,price,color,country,sale,size, arr):#створення змінних
        self.material = material
        self.price = price
        self.color = color
        self.country = country
        self.sale = sale
        self.size = size
        if self.country == "USA":
            self.price += self.price * 0.1
        if self.size_lst == "S":
            self.price -= self.price * 0.6

    def __str__(self):#метод повернення змінних
        return f'material-{self.material}, price- {self.price}, color- {self.color}, country- {self.country}, sale- {self.sale}, size- {self.size}'
```

Comment: как тогда визывать конструктор

Comment: ну вот вы его и вызыаете:
`specimen = Clothes(*arg, arr)`
конструктор вызывается неявно, в момент создания объекта